# database with array-like support?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I've got some information to store, let's dumb it down to food to create an example.
A recipe contains 1 or more ingredients, each ingredient has also got an amount.

So a recipe (one row in a table called recipe) could contain:

`id : 0
name : something disgusting
ingredientid1 : 0
ingredientamount1 : 20
ingredientid2 : 1
ingredientamount2: 6
..etc`

I've only got experience with mysql so far, but I'm willing to learn. In essence, I could serialize the ingredients to a string and store that string to then use a LIKE operator to find all recipes with a specific ingredient... but I would be disgusted by a solution like that.

The goal is to make the end-user able to give the server a list of ingredients to get a list of recipes returned, which can be made with those ingredients.

How would I do something like this without using a LIKE operator?

Comment: An array is probably not the right way to model such a relationship.  I would normalize it to a `food` table, `ingredient` table, and `food_ingredient_map` table.

Comment: you can try [nosql](https://www.udemy.com/blog/nosql-tutorial/)

Comment: @Brandon `food_ingredient_map` sounds interesting, but could you elaborate a bit on it?

Comment: @RajibGhosh: or use Postgres with a key/value store (`hstore`) or `json`. Postgres is starting to be a serious contender for the NoSQL bunch (because you get the best of both worlds). But this problem can easily (and efficiently) be stored in a relational model as well.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter, `food_ingredient_map` is exactly, what does `RecIngr` in my answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should implement it as separate table:

```
Recipe('id', 'name'...)
Ingredients('id', 'recipe_id', 'name', 'amount')
```

Then, you can simply get all ingredients by `WHERE recipe_id = x`

Also, if you want to share ingredients with any recipes. you should use tree tables, like:

```
Recipe('id', 'name')
Ingredients('id', 'name')
RecIngr('recipe_id', 'ingr_id', 'amount')
```

Then, you can get all recipe ingredients by join:

```
select i.name, ri.amount From Ingredients i
inner join RecIngr ri on ri.ingr_id=i.id
where ri.recipe_id = x
```

Comment: Ah yeah I was planning to have a table of ingredients, but then how would I create a recipe with a "random" amount of ingredients?

Comment: It's about business logic, not about data structure. You can set random/any amount, when insert rows to your database

Comment: AH! The edit makes it very clear to me! I like the solution, as it's elegant and doesn't completely bloat the database with unneeded variables either. Thanks a lot :)

Thanks @everyone!